# What is the most straightforward and battle tested way to deal with symlinks in a React Native monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I made a monorepo with React, React Native, TypeScript, Lerna and Yarn Workspaces.

By the end, I always had some issues with a package not found because of symlinks.

Is there a known processus or tool that is battle tested and simple to deploy to make a monorepo to share code between between React and React Native without the hell of symlinks management and without a ton of custom configuration ?

Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Yarn Workspaces, I wrote a package to help you with the configuration to resolve symlinks, [react-native-yarn-workspaces-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-yarn-workspaces-v2).
I use React, React Native and Electron in a mono-repo and it works fine for me.